# Repeat Case Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case

```
SELECT `pur_view`.`pro_id` AS `pro_id`,
       coalesce(sum((CASE WHEN (`pur_view`.`ware_id` = 1) THEN `pur_view`.`qty` END)),0) AS `Ware_1`,
       coalesce(sum((CASE WHEN (`pur_view`.`ware_id` = 3) THEN `pur_view`.`qty` END)),0) AS `Ware_2`,
       coalesce(sum((CASE WHEN `pur_view`.`ware_id` THEN `pur_view`.`qty` END)),0) AS `total`
FROM `pur_view`
GROUP BY `pur_view`.`pro_id`
```

And i need to repeat ware_id dynamically please help me

Answer (score 0):

Seem you can use procedure with cursor to do it. We need select distinct ware_id first. And foreach it to select.

But I think that is complex way. The simple way to select normally, and use php or C ... to convert it to format that you want.